# add an entry to the DPDB in aframe

Tags: aframe, webvr

I'm using AFRAME in an app for the Pico Goblin device.

Unsurprisingly, I'm getting the "No DPDB device match." error and the camera moves at the wrong speed and appears upside down.

I realise this is because this device is unlikely to be in the official webvr-polyfill DPDB.json

Is it possible to add devices to this file and use within aframe?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the repo where the dpdb file lives: https://github.com/immersive-web/webvr-polyfill-dpdb

You can indeed submit PRs there. A-Frame will pick it up in the next version.

In the meantime you can have a custom build of A-Frame that points to your fork of the [webvr-polyfill](https://github.com/immersive-web/webvr-polyfill) that [fetches your own DPDB.json](https://github.com/immersive-web/webvr-polyfill/blob/e2958490653bfcda4df83881d554bcdb641cf45b/src/config.js#L63)